# Replied Message ID - Microsoft-graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

If I reply to a message using the API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-reply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
, then where do I get the response id? Response is empty.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a response (or Location) header with either Send or Reply because they are asynchronous operations on the Exchange side (generally in the Graph if you used the Prefer return=minimal header you should get back a location response header with the Id of the item but because these ops are async there is no such Id at the time its accepted).

If you use CreateReply https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createreply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http that will give you a draft item to work with and if you use immutableId's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id then you always have a reference to the response.